# How to let a user choose from a list of menu options

Tags: tables, touch-screen, multi-selection

I have the following task: Design a website which offers menu options for a week, whereas on each day you basically have 2 options to choose from (Soup is always fixed):

- Soup
- Menu 1
- Menu 2

Now I would like to display a website which contains 5 columns (vertical) which show the days Monday through Friday. A user may log in to the website, then choose for each day if he/she wants Menu 1 or 2 (or nothing). It will probably look like this (columns/row-wise, not design-wise; ignore the lower part).

[image: Example]

Now I'm stuck on how I would want the user to select an item (and also to be able to de-select items in case he wants to later on).

The whole thing is intended to be used on a touchscreen in full-screen mode mounted in the office. There is a keyboard/mouse available but it would be better if it could be operated by touching.

I thought of a checkbox, but this would allow Multi-Selection, Radio Buttons .. where would I place them? A drop-down? Looks somewhat strange. ....

Do you have any better ideas? Any good examples?

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to UX.SE. Quick tip - users are never "dumb". They may be "new" or "novice" (vs. intermediate or expert), but are never "dumb". While we all undoubtedly think it at some point, don't externalize it... or you'll eventually slip and externalize it to the wrong person. That just makes for a bad day.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason why the user needs to see the Saturday menu on Tuesday? If not, present options only for that day (default always to today on opening) and if the user needs to select for another day she can choose the day and then see the options for that day.

This will also allow more room for the options because the type would have to be pretty small to fit into seven columns. And I imagine you'll be asked to squeeze a description in too, so better to allow more space.

[image]

Comment: Actually a user should be able to order for the full next week (which essentially has turned out to be Mo-Thu only). This is because you do not order for the next day, but at least 2 days in advance (and even more over the weekend). Your layout is pretty clever I have to say, so thank you.

Comment: I like this design. Since you want to urge touch, I would rely on big clickable areas instead of classic UI elements. One click to select, another to deselect.
Would you need an option to opt out? if so, a "none" option might be helpful. You might also want to think side arrows to navigate forward and back through the days, as well as adding a date range and /or dates to the days.