# Weekly food menu creation problem

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, ux-field

Currently I do single menu creation like:

[image: Single Creation]

But I would like to follow the business' pattern to improve the usability. Every Sunday, they are posting the menu for the whole week (except weekends) so I thought of doing this:

[image: Multiple creation]

The problem with that is the form got bigger and user might get intimidated.

I could have do Accordion or Wizard instead to make it a bit easier

**BUT** the label/header that specifies what day is the form group for will not make any sense anymore by having `Availability` field.

**AND** without the `Availability` field, how would I handle the dates? Even if I assume the order of the days by adding 1 from the previous group of form I'll be **needing** the week of the month I'll be making the calculations from.

Comment: There is a very similar question with possible solutions at http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/73227/how-to-let-a-user-choose-from-a-list-of-menu-options/86614#86614

Comment: @EricStoltz looked at question. His problem is how to represent the data that has been created to the customer/user. My question asks for how to create the data to show. Data in this context is the "menu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a single Availability field for the whole week:

- <strike>which states the starting date and ending date: the user selects two dates, and every day in between has the menu available</strike>
- which states the starting date **"Week starting the 2th of February"**: this could be achieved using a [date picker](https://material.io/guidelines/components/pickers.html#pickers-usage) that limits the days the user can choose to only Mondays
- which has two dropdowns: Starting week and Month (or even have Year but highly unlikely). In case the week of the month does not start on Monday, you can just calculate/check that always on the server side

This way you can omit including the field for each day.

Comment: Have a point, but how? I mean, using dropdown that has pre-calculated option? but how many options? with that, I'll be having infinite options or until we have discovered the end date of the world. jokes aside, I know I can limit it but what if the user wants to keep on planning? that's a downside that I can see with this solution

Comment: @jen maybe I am misunderstanding, but I mean the same way the user is selecting date right now. The thing is you would need to keep a way to make a category per week or similar. Let me know if I was not clear.

Comment: I thought you were saying have a single Availability field for the whole that is a dropdown which has an option like: "Week 1 of Feb", "Week 2 of Feb", etc. Still +1 for making me have that idea.

Comment: @jen I meant a [datepicker](https://material.io/guidelines/components/pickers.html#pickers-usage), where the user selects the first day of the week. You could limit the picker so the user can only choose Mondays, for example.

Comment: Could use that instead too. Less hassle instead of having 2 dropdown.

Comment: @jen Also selecting "First week of ..." can be confusing if for example the month starts on a Thursday.

Comment: Never thought of that. Ok so: 1 availability/starting week field for the whole form and have datepicker that allows monday values only OR still have 2 dropdown: week number + month and calculate to get the monday of that week on processing. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @jen I'll edit it. Well, the idea behind the two dates (first option) is that any Monday in between those dates will apply (this option is more an alternative).

Comment: The option with ending date is not feasible. Food menu will always be from Monday to Friday. What if the ending date the user has selected is on Thursday? So only, starting week and month dropdown and just calculate it's Monday date OR datepicker that allows only Monday to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the "availability" (does that mean the date to which the menu applies?) after the day of the week, e.g.

> Monday, 06 Feb 17    *(better to name the month, since there isn't a world-standard for date representation)*

...and then discard that separate field.

If you're worried about the amount of space consumed, you could use paging (is that what an "accordion" is?  I don't know that term).

You could also put up a calendar widget to page between weeks, unless the menus are never made up more than a week in advance.

**EDIT:**

You could also, as you suggest in your comment, put 2 (or 3) small dropdowns after the day-name to pick week, month, and perhaps year.

Comment: the problem I'm having is not the format/pattern of the availability input... well at least that's how I understand your answer. look at @Alvaro's answer

Comment: What do you think would happen if you chose to put the date after the day-of-week name?  What would break?

Comment: now that's more clear. I just got an idea from your answer. 1 availability input that has 2 dropdowns: week number, month of the year. Consider editing your answer and put this in if I would choose this as right answer.